# deconvolutional/upsampling layer specification for fully convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to understand the implementation of the [fully convolutional neural network model](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf).  In the paper, authors discuss three models: fcn8, fcn16 and fcn 32. 
[image].

Here is the detailed description of fcn16 in the paper

```
We first divide the output stride in half by predicting
from a 16 pixel stride layer. We add a 1 × 1 convolution
layer on top of pool4 to produce additional class predictions.
We fuse this output with the predictions computed
on top of conv7 (convolutionalized fc7) at stride 32 by
adding a 2× upsampling layer and summing6 both predictions
(see Figure 3). We initialize the 2× upsampling to bilinear
interpolation, but allow the parameters to be learned
as described in Section 3.3. Finally, the stride 16 predictions
are upsampled back to the image.
```

There does not have explicit specification on the kernel size of deconvolutional filter for the skip layer from pool4 and the prediction layer from original convolutional layer 7.  Also,  authors mention that add a 2* upsampling layer on top of conv7. Does that mean a stride=2? Also for this case, what should be the kernel size of deconvolutional layer?